# Charge density of infinite sheet of negative charge in presence of external charge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

> A tiny hole is made in an infinite, conducting sheet of charge. Assume initial charge density to be $-\sigma$. We put a positive charge $+q$ in this hole. Find the charge density of the sheet now as a function of radial distance $r$ from the positive charge.

**Claim**: My classmates claim that the answer would be undefined, as circles of positive and negative charge would alternate at infinitesimal intervals (apologies if I couldn't get this part across).

**My problem**: I am having difficulty coming to terms with this answer, as it seems physically impossible for the charge density to be undefined. Unfortunately, I am unable to mathematically work out a solution to this.

**What I need**: Can the above claim of undefined answer be justified? If yes, why? If not, how could I possibly approach the problem?

*Background note*: Not a homework question, I came up with it randomly.

---

**EDIT**: After some thought, I believe the answer is simply that the charge density is $-\infty$ near the $+q$ charge, and unchanged everywhere else. The reasoning is that the positive charge acts as a sink (hopefully that's the correct term). As long as there is a net positive charge at any distance, electrons get attracted. At steady state, the maximum distance there is a net positive charge tends to zero. Hopefully I was able to explain my reasoning.

Comment: Interesting question.   I assume that the $+q$ charge is fixed in place, and has a given radius that matches the size of the hole.  Then I don't see how there can be alternating rings.  On the other hand, maybe you haven't defined the problem carefully enough.

Comment: “Find the charge density of the sheet as a function of the radial distance r from the positive charge “ doesn’t make sense to me. Sure you’re not talking about the electric field a distance r in space away from the positive charge on the sheet?

Comment: I did fear that it wasn't defined well, it didn't take long to make the question. Yes, the $+q$ charge is fixed in place, and we assume that it fills the tiny hole. Why is asking about the charge density not a sensible question? If it helps, I meant the variation of surface charge density with increasing distance from the $+q$ charge.